# Join this eloquent laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

I recieve correctly this two messages , but I need to JOIN this two results with Laravel5.

Could anyone helps to me ? Or it's any possibilities to doing this with other form?

```
$mensajes = Messageuser::find(1)->conversaciones()->get();
$mensajes2 = Messageuser::find(4)->conversaciones()->get();
echo $mensajes;
echo $mensajes2;
```

**UPDATE**

The MessageUser

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class MessageUser extends Model {
    protected $table ="message_user";

    public function conversaciones(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message','id_message','id');
    } 

}
```

The Message model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model {

    protected $table="messages";

    public function chat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MessageUser','id');
    }

}
```

**UPDATED2**

When I tried to sort in the view appear Illegal offset type

```
$mensajes = Messageuser::find(1)->conversaciones()->get();
        $mensajes2 = Messageuser::find(4)->conversaciones()->get();
        $mensajes = $mensajes->keyBy('created_at');
        $prueba = $mensajes->merge($mensajes2->keyBy('created_at'));
        return view('admin.msj')->with('pruebas',$prueba);
```

Comment: please add the code that defines the relations `conversaciones`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is a `hasMany` and will therefor return a collection set, not one "echoable" thing:

```
$mensajes = Messageuser::find(1)->conversaciones()->get();
$mensajes2 = Messageuser::find(4)->conversaciones()->get();
\dd($mensajes, $mensajes2);
```

This will return two `Collection` objects dumped. Please also note that you can use:

```
$mensajes = Messageuser::find(1)->conversaciones;
```

To get the same return set.

Now you want to join the results, you could use the built-in method for `merge` from the `Collection` class:

```
$mensajes->merge($mensajes2);
```

To merge based on created_at:

```
$mensajes = $mensajes->keyBy('created_at');
$mensajes->merge($mensajes2->keyBy('created_at'));
```

Comment: This works perfect , how can I sort this merge with created_at ?

Comment: I have problem and I put the code in Updated2 , you're understand to me ? I need to sort with the date of creation about messages.

Comment: please create a new question with your issue, do not use SO as a forum, it's a Q&A, see the [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)